# What is the difference between 恥ずかしい and 気恥ずかしい?

Tags: word-choice

the [goo definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/53485/meaning/m0u/%E6%B0%97%E6%81%A5%E3%81%9A%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%84/)  of 気恥ずかしい:

> なんとなく恥ずかしい。きまりが悪い。

I don't really understand the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「気」 is a ***prefix*** in 「気恥{きは}ずかしい」.　It is read 「き」 or 「け」, depending on the word it is  attached to.

This prefix adds the meaning of ***"somewhat", "kind of", "to an extent"***, etc. to the verb or adjective that it attaches to.  Note that these are what 「なんとなく」 means at least roughly.

Thus, 「**気**恥ずかしい」 means "somewhat embarrassed", "a little bit ashamed", etc. whereas the plain 「恥ずかしい」 means "embarrassed", "ashamed", etc.

Common words using this prefix include:

「気{け}だるい」 = "somewhat dull", "kind of listless", etc.

「気忙{きぜわ}しい」 = "somewhat fidgety"

[デジタル大辞泉 explains it this way](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%B0%97-49796#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88).

> 動詞・形容詞に付いて、なんとなく、漠然としたなどの意を表す。「気おされる」「気だるい」